# How to make a java swing popup window with combo box and 2 buttons?

Tags: java, swing, popup

I need to make a popup box with with a combo box and a couple of buttons. Please could someone advice on the best way to achieve this? I've had a look around and all I can find is alert boxes. Is this possible or will I need to create a whole new frame?

Comment: what exactly the problem? you can add whatever component to a popupMenu - opening the popup of a contained combo is not easily possible, though, because the rule is one popup simultaneousely

Comment: @kleopatra still in sun-bug-parades

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the JOptionPane to achieve this. Please refer to the link below which explains this with sample code:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input

Answer (score 5):

[JOptionPane.showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) may be good enough if you are willing to leave how exactly the options are presented up to the UI.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Answer (score 1):

```
I need to make a popup box with with a combo box and a couple of buttons
```

1) don't use another `JFrame` as popup window, use `JFrame` with `JOptionPane/JDialog/JWindow` these container are same as `JFrame`, but can take parent and owner

2) don't forget to [setParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29)

3) depends if you needed `decorated` window then use `JDialog`, don't forget look for `setModal() or ModalityTypes`, if undecorated then use `JWindow`

4) don't create lots of `JOptionPane/JDialog/JWindow` on fly, becasue there Object are still in JVM memory, create this Container once and re-use that (by removing child) for another Action